# Angular 12 string interpolation

Tags: angular, string-interpolation, angular12

App receive some data from server via rest calls. Based on this response we can build some context object and string. Example:

```
const contextObject = {name: 'World'};
const expression : string = 'Hello {{name}}';
```

So finally I would like to have 'Hello World' string which I can bind in HTML template.

Can somebody help and explain how to evaluate this expression in Angular 12?

---

@update Maybe somebody with better angular background can explain how i18n works with such scenarious? As task looks quite similar to replace all plaseholders with an object from context...
I as well was looking in some angular src and start with something like

```
    const context = {name: "World"};
    const expressionParser = new Parser(new Lexer());
    let parseInterpolation = expressionParser.parseInterpolation("Hello {{name}}", "", 0);
...
```

but that's it. Have no ide what to do next...

Comment: String interpolation in angular like `{{ ... }}` only works in html code, so you will have to use a regex to replace everything between the curly brackets.

Comment: Do you have an idea about alternative solutions which we can have?

Comment: Can you clarify on the expression variable? Is it coming from the rest API as well?

Comment: Yes, both expression and context object comes from server

Comment: @VitaliiFedoryshyn Can you be a little more specific and provide a context for us to understand better what you're trying to do? Despite your answers, we're only guessing what you're trying to do.
Do you want to replace {{name}} with the value? Do you evaluate the string yourself already? What do you mean by "bind to a html template?" Can you please update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Write a function which take two parameter string expression and context object. return string as which is result of expression evaluation.

Comment: @VitaliiFedoryshyn For that given sample and question the correct answer is posted. If it does not satisfy your needs provide context, and clarify what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something angular will perform for you. It's something you'd have to code yourself like so:

```js
let expression = "Hello {{name}}";
for(let key in contextObject )
{
    expression = expression.replace(`{{${key}}}`, contextObject[key]);
}
```

Simply replace all keys in the contextObject with their values.

You can utilize angular libraries & services to sanitize the string.

Comment: Thank you, as I understood using this simple string replacement is currently the best alternative option

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports template evaluation during runtime with JIT. The new Ivy renderer uses an AOT compiler, and is only suitable for build time usage. It is also the default pipeline.

I highly recommend to avoid going down including the run-time version of the compiler and creating templates in the browser as it's extremely slow. And will increase your bundle sizes significantly.

Rather creating templates and evaluating them run-time. I'd recommend to create the various components that you can dynamically render when needed.

So you'd essentially end up with something like:

```html
Hello <Text [value]="contextObject.name"></Text>
```

If you're creating the RestAPI as well, you can easily create a tree of components with various data to pass along.

If your expression that you receive from your API is

```
Hello {{name}}
```

You'd have to parse it yourself, to generate the component tree you need to render a view in angular.

Your other solution is run-time compiling which is very slow and discouraged.

Ideally you should have your API provide some sort of structure that can be represented as your view.

```json
{
   "children": [
      {
         "type": "Heading1",
         "children": [
            {
               "type": "Text",
               "value": "Hello",
            },
            {
               "type": "Text",
               "value": "World",
            },
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Which then could be easily translated to

```html
<Heading1>
   <Text [vale]="Hello"></Text>
   <Text [vale]="World"></Text>
</Heading1>
```

For run-time compilation you should consult with google, as there are  resources available very sparsely.

However this demonstrates the basic flow of how to compile a component runtime.

**Note** This won't work out of the box, as you need to include several other modules in your application.

```js
// Must clear cache.
this.compiler.clearCache();

// Define the component using Component decorator.
const component = Component({
    template: '<div>This is the dynamic template. Test value: {{test}}</div>',
    styles: [':host {color: red}']
})(class
{
    test = 'some value';
});

// Define the module using NgModule decorator.
const module = NgModule({
    declarations: [component]
})(class
{
});

// Asynchronously (recommended) compile the module and the component.
this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module)
    .then(factories =>
    {
        // Get the component factory.
        const componentFactory = factories.componentFactories[0];
        // Create the component and add to the view.
        const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
        // Modifying the property and triggering change detection.
        setTimeout(() => componentRef.instance.test = 'some other value', 2000);
    });
```

**Dima Slivin** provides a great article on this on his blog:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/compiling-angular-templates-runtime-dima-slivin/